# Why don't use IP fragment/combine to tackle UDP maximum segment size?

Tags: udp, segment

We know that UDP has a max segment size (65,507 bytes) due to size limit of a single IP packet, but IP also has a fragment/recombine feature, so why doesn't network layer use this feature to tackle oversize UDP segment? That is, when a UDP segment whose size is greater than one IP packet is handed to network layer, IP can first fragment it, using multiple IP packets to route them, and at the destination host, these fragments can be combined together to form the original UDP segment. This way, network layer can handle arbitrary large UDP segment, and transport layer doesn't need to worry UDP segment size, so why isn't this used in practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP fragmentation happens at a lower level than UDP and it's basically to ensure IP datagrams (not UDP datagrams: I'll call the IP ones "packets" below even though the RFC confusingly calls them datagrams) can get from source to destination even when there's a point in the middle that cannot handle the original size of the IP packet.

The limitation on UDP is *not* IP, it's the UDP header, which has a 16-bit value for the length:

```
Octet
      +-------------+
    0 | Source port |
    1 |             |
      +-------------+
    2 | Destination |
    3 |        port |
      +-------------+
    4 | Length      |
    5 |             |
      +-------------+
    6 | Checksum    |
    7 |             |
      +-------------+
```

In other words, if you send a 60K UDP datagram from a system that allows 61K IP packets, it will go of okay.

If it encounters a network segment that only allows 31K IP packets, IP will fragment it and recombine it later.

That's happening at the *lower* level. Even once the UDP datagram is recombined, it has the same length limitation due to the 16-bit length field in its header.

Answer (score 1):

> why isn't this used in practice?

It ***is*** used in practice. The issue isn't here, it is that UDP doesn't have any protocol for requesting retransmission of a lost fragment, so a datagram that has been fragmented and whose fragments don't all arrive is lost entirely.

If you're asking why it isn't used to exceed the 65507 byte limit, it can't be. That limit is imposed by the 16-bit UDP header field size, less the IP header (20 bytes), less the UDP header (8 bytes). However in practice the real limit is the path MTU. 534 bytes is often recommended as a practical maximum.